# Why does Rambam say "gentiles marriages' are not recognized" in Melachim uMilchamot, Chapter 8, verse 3?

Tags: gentiles, rambam, melachim-kings-book-of

He mentions this as he clarifies the rules about having relations with/marrying a captive during war:

"Relations with a yefat toar are only permitted while she is in captivity as the verse states "If you see... among the prisoners."

This license is permitted whether the woman is a virgin or not, even if she is married, for the **gentiles' marriages are not recognized**."

Can someone explain why this is so? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Lechem Mishneh explains that although it is generally forbidden to have relations with the wife of a gentile, nevertheless being that regarding a “Yefat To’ar” the Torah refers to her as a “beautiful wife”, it can be derived that it is permitted even if she is married, and the Rambam explains that the reason for this is because the marriage of a gentile is in a different category, being that one would not be punishable by death for having relations with a gentile’s wife.